# Set column field with another field using workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server

I create a simple workflow using Sharepoint 2010 designer. basically `set ProductCopied to` `[%CurrentIte:EData Process%]`. EData Process field is a field where value from Manage Metadata.

The issue is when i added a record to the list associate with the workflow. I recieved an error  in workflow status "Failed on Start (retrying)". then the in a couple minutes the workflow completed and copied the value from EData Process field to ProductCopied. The problem is that value copied to ProductCopied field contain additional string like this "|2301f448-2c99-8aa0-b0f8-ad3273f12176"

What I have tried:

- Reboot the web front end server
- IIS Reset on web front end
- Restart the timer job on App and web frontend
- Clear configuration cache

Note: I also recently upgrade to SharePOint 2010 September 2014 CU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new calculate column and add the following forumula
=LEFT([ProductCopied],FIND("|",[ProductCopied])-1)

based on the solution:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_28251089.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest some troubleshooting first. Write the `[%CurrentItem:EData Process%]` into a string variable and write that variable into the workflow history log. Then check how that string looks in the history.

Maybe you need an additional workflow step to strip the GUID from the text.